# SvgViewbox doesn't show tooltip on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg, sharpvectors

I'm using SharpVectors library in my WPF app to display SVG icons instead of the traditional PNGs. I'm using the following basic pattern throughout my XAML:

```
<Button ToolTip="My doodad">
    <svgc:SvgViewbox Height="16" Width="16" Margin="2" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/svg/mydoodad.svg" />
</Button>
```

The problem is that the tooltip I set on my button doesn't show through the `SvgViewbox`. It only shows when mouse is hovering over the button's 2px margin that isn't covered by the `SvgViewbox` element.

Contrast with this, where tooltip shows over the entire button surface, as expected:

```
<Button ToolTip="My doodad">
    <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" Margin="2">
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/png/mydoodad.png"></Image>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

I tried setting the tooltip on the `SvgViewbox` directly, but it makes no difference. What else can I do to make this work?

Comment: `WPF` can display Vector Graphics out of the box! `Path` or `Rectangle` or `Ellipse` are just all vectors. If you want to use vector graphics they need to be in the right format, I use `Inkscape` to export vector images as xaml files. Then use `ViewBox`.

Comment: I will consider this method, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `SvgViewbox`, but try to set property **`IsHitTestVisible`** to **`False`** for the `SvgViewbox`:

```
<Button ToolTip="My doodad">
    <svgc:SvgViewbox IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="2" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/svg/mydoodad.svg" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Yesss! Thank you! :)